# How to draw a rotatable and zoomable sphere?

Tags: opengl, rotation, windows

My game is a sort of business simulation game of Earth, and I want the main interface to be just like a google earth view. Is there a way to do this with built in OpenGL features or do I have to implement the engine myself.

Comment: What is your target platform? PC, Browser, Tablet, Console?

Comment: PC, and I want to write the project in C++.

Comment: That's doable, render a sphere and apply transformation matrix to it. Judging from your question, you need to read some basic OpenGL tutorials if you want to do that yourself. Otherwise get a 3D engine (Unity, Ogre, etc) and work from there.

Comment: I think your question is a little vague, What do you mean by built-in features ? OpenGL is a rendering API, so you can render whatever you want. I don't understand if the question is about what to do or how to do it but as Krom said you need to read some openGL tutorials, looking for a math library like glm will also help.

Comment: Your question is simply a combination of a few other questions. Break apart your question into its component parts, i.e. How to draw a sphere, how to zoom in/out and how to rotate/orbit around an object. Search for each separately and combine the answers on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating the vertices for a sphere using one of the algorithms from [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31308/algorithm-for-creating-spheres), then you can orbit around it using the strategy [described here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/45408/7191).

If you should use an engine or not isn't really something we can answer here. It depends on how long you want to spend creating the required functionality yourself. Typically, it's recommended to use an existing engine instead of creating your own.

As an aside, you might want to consider a divide and conquer strategy for some of your problems, like this one. Breaking the problem down into more generalized components will often make it easier to find answers and solve your problems faster.